# Windows Phone test fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

Following [this](http://codingsolutions.blogspot.se/2010/03/windows-phone-7-tdd-kata-using-mvvm-and.html) tutorial and running into trouble.

```
 [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
    public void VerifyPropertyNameMethod_NonExistentPropertyString_ThrowsException()
    {
        var customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "June", LastName = "Smith" };
        var sut = new CustomerViewModel(_customerRepository, customer);
        sut.VerifyPropertyName("NonExistentPropertyName");

    }
```

The test fails with the message seen below. The test obviosuly throws an exception, but it is supposed to! Why does the test then fail?

```
 VerifyPropertyNameMethod_NonExistentPropertyString_ThrowsException : FailedTest method FirstOnSiteWindowsPhoneApp.AppCode.Tests.Unit.CustomerViewModelTests.VerifyPropertyNameMethod_NonExistentPropertyString_ThrowsException threw exception: 
FirstOnSiteWindowsPhoneApp.AppCode.Domain.VerifyPropertyNameException: Exception of type 'FirstOnSiteWindowsPhoneApp.AppCode.Domain.VerifyPropertyNameException' was thrown.
at FirstOnSiteWindowsPhoneApp.AppCode.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel.VerifyPropertyName(String propertyName) in CustomerViewModel.cs: line 29
at FirstOnSiteWindowsPhoneApp.AppCode.Tests.Unit.CustomerViewModelTests.VerifyPropertyNameMethod_NonExistentPropertyString_ThrowsException() in CustomerViewModelTests.cs: line 53
```

Comment: By the looks of things the value `NonExistantPropertyName` is being flagged as invalid and the exception thrown. Can you clarify your question and maybe give a bit more detail as to where you are struggling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected exception is of the wrong type. It should be:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(VerifyPropertyNameException))]
```

That's what the tutorial shows as well, so I'm not sure why you've got `typeof(Exception)` instead...

`ExpectedException` expects *exactly* the specified type of exception, not just anything deriving from it. Note that personally I prefer `Assert.Throws<...>(() => ...)` as that way you limit the scope of the code which is expected to throw, but that's a separate matter.